# Where are the images when move a mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I've moved my mediawiki to a new server and uploaded all of the images to the image directory.  I can see all of the content but none of the images.    does anyone know what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't copy the images with the whole migration ? When you upload a picture on mediawiki, it creates seperated folders for every image...god knows why. in your image section. `rootfolder/images..`

so if you simply take the pictures and upload them later on AGAIN, that mediawiki creates new subfolders in /images...

take the old images folder and copy it with all the pictures inside and it will work